# assign attribute to $scope in the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a small problem in AngularJs which is:

I'd like to assign a static to the $scope.customer.LikeProfile

```
$scope.customer.LikeProfil = 0;
```

and I tried to display the value in the window.alert on my view page

```
window.alert($scope.customer.LikeProfil);
```

this instruction allert me and display the error at the console of my browser :

**TypeError: Cannot set property 'LikeProfil' of undefined
    at k.$scope.addIdea**

What I'd like to do in the controller is to add a new customer(object) to the database using $resource and here is my code

**controller.js:**

```
app.controller('CustomerCreationCtrl', ['$scope','PostCustomerFactory', '$location',
function ($scope, PostCustomerFactory, $location) {
  $scope.createNewCustomer = function(){
      $scope.customer.LikeProfil = 0;
    window.alert($scope.customer.LikeProfil);
    $scope.customer.FirstName = "Rochdi (Name by default";
      PostCustomerFactory.create($scope.customer);
      $location.path("/customers");
  };
}]);
```

**service.js**

```
services.factory('PostIdeaFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(url + '/ideaService/postIdea', {}, {
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    });
});
```

**add-view.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputBirthDate" class="col-md-2 control-label">Birth of Date</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputBirthDate" placeholder="..." ng-model="customer.BirthDate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPseudo" class="col-md-2 control-label">Pseudo</label>
       <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputPseudo" placeholder="..." ng-model="customer.Pseudo">
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm m-t-10" ng-click="createNewCustomer()">SUBMIT FORM</button>
         </div>
     </div>
```

for the Pseudo and BirthDate they're just properties in customer and my goal is to assign a static value to LikeProfil and FirstName properties and show them in the pop up box (window.alert) in the view in short , don't care about Pseudo and BirthDate properties it's not my problem and they work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to define `customer` as an `object` first befor setting its property to something

```
$scope.customer ={};
```

your final code will be(controller.js)

```
app.controller('CustomerCreationCtrl', ['$scope','PostCustomerFactory', '$location',
function ($scope, PostCustomerFactory, $location) {
 $scope.customer ={};
  $scope.createNewCustomer = function(){
      $scope.customer.LikeProfil = 0;
    window.alert($scope.customer.LikeProfil);
    $scope.customer.FirstName = "Rochdi (Name by default";
      PostCustomerFactory.create($scope.customer);
      $location.path("/customers");
  };
}]);
```